Nginx configuration with Angular localization, Error 404 Not Found on browser page refresh
I have an angular application with localization for English and Spanish.
My directory structure looks like this
/var/www/html/
├── angular-app/
│   ├── en/
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── other files ...
│   └── es/
│       ├── index.html
│       └── other files ...

I have the following code in the nginx.conf file
http {
    # Custom settings
    map $http_accept_language $accept_language {
            ~*^en en;
            ~*^es es;
    }
...

And the following configuration
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/angular-app;

    # Fallback to default language if no preference defined by browser
    if ($accept_language ~ "^$") {
        set $accept_language "en";
    }

    # Redirect "/" to Angular application in the preferred language of the browser
    rewrite ^/$ /$accept_language;

    # assets within the root
    location /assets {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

Now the issue is with refreshing the page, it generates a 404. I did some research and everybody is talking about using try_files to resolve this issue, but unfortunately after multiple tries I am still unable to figure out what I did wrong.
Any help is appreciated.
